# How do I do this clever casting in C?

Tags: c, casting, macros, c-preprocessor

You can see what I'm trying to do below:

```
typedef struct image_bounds {
    int xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax;
} image_bounds;

#define IMAGE_BOUNDS(X) ((image_bounds *)(X));

typedef struct {
    image_bounds bounds;
    float dummy;
} demo;

int
main(void) {
    demo my_image;

    /* this works fine */
    ((image_bounds *)(&my_image))->xmin = 10;

    /* why doesn't this work? i get the following error:
    /* In function main:
      cast.c:20: error: expected expression before = token
    */    
    IMAGE_BOUNDS(&my_image)->xmin = 20;

    return 0;
}
```

As you can see from above the **C** cast works but the macro version does not, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you expand your macro, it doesn't appear that you are trying to set any field, i.e., there's no reference to .xmin, .ymin, or even .dummy, the lvalue just expands to a pointer to my_image.

Comment: A useful trick for the future might be to explicitly run it through preprocessor (cpp) if you have such a possibility - it will show you the text after the macro expansion, so any errors will be much more visible. for your example it showed the macro expanded to "((image_bounds *)(&my_image));->xmin = 20;" which helps to spot the error.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to lose the semicolon from the definition of IMAGE_BOUNDS:

```
#define IMAGE_BOUNDS(X) ((image_bounds *)(X))
```

Comment: You can't call yourself a C programmer if you haven't developed a blind spot for semicolons!

Answer (score 2):

In the version without macros you have `->xmin` before the `=`, in the one with macros you don't.

Comment: yeah sorry that was just a typo :(